# Mathematica, ComplexListPlot: how can I make the "Joined" lines and the plotted points different colors?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

1) The plotted points and the "Joined" lines are always the same color. Can I make them different?
2) Sometimes the number-labels don't show up, as with the lowest point, sitting on the X axis. M. is clever about locating the label relative to the point, so why not with this point? Here is the code, followed by the plot it makes.

```
tow[0] = 1
tow[n_] := seed^tow[n-1]
seed =  I
ComplexListPlot[Table[Labeled[N[tow[i]], i], {i, 1, 30}], 
PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Red, 
PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Smaller}]
```

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMwm3.png

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Show[
  ComplexListPlot[Table[N[tow[i]],{i,1,30}],
    PlotRange->All,PlotStyle->{Green,PointSize[.03]}],
  ComplexListPlot[Table[Labeled[N[tow[i]],i],{i,1,30}],
    PlotRange->All,Joined->True,PlotStyle->Red]
]
```